# Why doesn't my String/selector concatenation work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation, string-concatenation

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work:

```
var cfHTML = '<div class="touch-feild" onclick="showPreview('+$(this).find('.feed-thumb')+')"></div>';
```

I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Hope someone can help me out here. I guess it must be a pretty simple question :-)

Thanks

Comment: what you want to pass as parameter of  feed-thumb element? id,any attribute?

Comment: `var cfHTML = '<div class="touch-feild" onclick="showPreview($(this).find(\'.feed-thumb\'))"></div>';`

Comment: In your code It would concatenate `[object Object]` to the string

Comment: I whant to pass a reference to specific selector of an element I am currently hovering. $(this) is the element I'm hovering and I want to catch the '.feed-thumb' inside that element and use it in my function "showPreview". Does that make sence?

Comment: Pranav C Balan - your suggestion didn't do the job ;-(

Answer (score 0):

It think what you want to accomplish is `onclick="showPreview($(this).find('.feed-thumb'))"` in your .

```
var cfHTML = '<div class="touch-feild" onclick="showPreview($(this).find(\'.feed-thumb\'))"></div>';
```

`$(this).find('.feed-thumb')` will give you jquery object not string.

Comment: jep! That is exactly what I whant. How do I acomplish that?

Comment: I want to use the append() to add the HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meen? Your code doesn't do what I want. I can log an [object object] in my showPreview function but it is not the right one. I cant log prop("class") or any other property/attribute on the object.